# spark standalone without hdfs

Tags: linux, windows, apache-spark

i've been trying a simple wordcount app on spark standalone.
I have 1 windows machine and 1 linux machine, 
Windows runs Master & slave 
Linux runs slave.

Connection was fast a simple.
i try to avoid using hdfs but i do want to work on a cluster.
My code so far is:

```
    String fileName = "full path at client";
    File file = new File(fileName);
    Path filePath = new Path(file);
    String uri= filePath.toURI().toString();
    SparkConf conf = new sparkConf().setAppName("stam").setMaster("spark://192.168.15.17:7077").setJars(new String[] { ..,.. });
    sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    sc.addFile(uri);
    JavaRDD<String> textFile = sc.textFile(SparkFiles.get(getOnlyFileName(fileName))).cache();
```

This fails with

> Input path does not exist:........
>   or
>   java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI

depends on what i try, the error is from the linux slave

Any idea if this possible ?
The file is being copied to all slaves work directories .
Please help

Comment: can you print the content of uri please. does it start with file:/// ?

Comment: Also, are you certain that both machines will be able to access the file using the path you give `textFile`?

Comment: That is the problem, i can't find the proper input to the textfile method!, i've just added the file through addFile, and SparkFiles.get only returns the path from the original driver machine (os windows). i know the file has been sent to the files directory in the executor's workDir, why can the path not be relative ? or why can't i just use %workFiles%filename, or something.

Comment: This cannot be done.
I've moved from standalone to yarn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done.
I've moved from standalone to yarn